# Retrieving Firebase Database String and converting String to Integer for label not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, integer

Saving data to Firebase and retrieving data to display in label is working but when I try to add an `Int` to the label it overwrites the label data.

I add to the label with

```swift
var pointsCount = 0

func addPoints(_ points: NSInteger) {
    pointsCount += points
    pointsLabel.text = "\(self.pointsCount)"
}
```

Then I save the label contents to Firebase as a string.

```swift
func saveToFirebase() {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let points: String = ("\(self.pointsCount)")

    let savedScores = ["points": points,
                       "blah": blah,
                       "blahblah": blahblah]

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID).updateChildValues(savedScores, withCompletionBlock:
        {
            (error, ref) in
            if let error = error
            {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            else
            {
                print("Data saved successfully!")
            }
    })
}
```

I retrieve the string from the Realtime Database and convert it to an Int.

```swift
func retrieveFromFirebase() {
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID).child("points").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
        (snapshot)
        in
        guard let points = snapshot.value as? String else { return }

        let pointsString = points

        if let pointsInt = NumberFormatter().number(from: pointsString) {
            let retrievedPoints = pointsInt.intValue
            self.pointsLabel.text = "\(retrievedPoints)"
        } else {
            print("NOT WORKING")
        }
}
```

The label displays the retrieved data from the database perfectly.

Then if I try to add more points to the label, it erases the retrieved data and starts adding from 0 as if the label displayed nil.

I've been searching for answers all day for what seems to be a rather simple problem but haven't been able to figure it out due to my lack of experience.

I have tried separating everything and saving the data as an integer and retrieving the data back as an integer but the issue seems to be from the addPoints function.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: just asking --- why don't you simply use string to your label instead of converting string -> number -> int -> string ? try use points direct  .

Comment: There are more strings in the block but even when I separate them and save them as integers I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being as simple as adding an 'if' statement to the points function.

Instead of...

```
func addPoints(_ points: NSInteger) {
pointsCount += points
pointsLabel.text = "\(self.pointsCount)"
}
```

It needed to be...

```
func addPoints(_ points: NSInteger) {
    if let text = self.pointsLabel.text, var pointsCount = Int(text)
    {
        pointsCount += points
        pointsLabel.text = "\(pointsCount)"
    }
}
```